# Watch and compile existing scss folder with compass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Hi I am working on a project which already comes with an scss and css folder with existing files within them. I have compass installed and I am trying to get it to watch the scss folder and compile the changes to the css folder. If i use

```
 compass create
```

it generates all of its own folders. If I use

```
 compass create . --bare --sass-dir "scss" --css-dir "css"
```

it says the config.rb file already exists. And if I use

```
 compass watch
```

it says there is nothing to compile. Any ideas where I am going wrong? Cheers!

Comment: What's the contents of the config.rb?  It's just a text file, if it doesn't match your directory structure, you can just edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run Sass with the `--compass` flag to load Compass. This makes it easy to slot Compass into an existing Sass project.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but stumbled across it when I encountered the same issue, interestingly running the following worked for me. Without `--force`, I encounted the same issue as OP when he tried the command without it, but with it included, it worked like a charm.

```
 compass create . --bare --sass-dir "scss" --css-dir "css" --force
```